# How to make the function tooltip disappear after the braces are removed in vscode?

Tags: tooltip, visual-studio-code

So I'm working on a language server extension for vscode.
I want the tooltip to disappear after the braces or some other triggering event has happened (I want it to basically work the same as for JavaScript tooltips).
I suppose the problem is with the language server I'm developing but I was wondering if you could help me find out what triggers the disappearance.

The disappearance at the end is because the gif loops. The tooltip stays there actually. Only pressing ESC triggers the removal.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not getting any responses here I asked the question on github vscode/Issues.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18498

It turns out that I was returning from the handler without adding a falsy SignatureHelp to the ResponseQueue.
I can confirm this fixes the problem.